# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AngularFireAuth

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, google-signin

We are tried login with google authentication using (Firebase/ionic2/angularjs2).Our code

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
   user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }
  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

but we are getting error :

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AngularFireAuth!
Error: No provider for AngularFireAuth!
```

Please guide to us what working in our code .

Comment: Try adding `AngularFireAuth` in `providers` array also, of `app.component.ts` by importing it there.

Comment: Did you add it in your `NgModule` under `imports` array?

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? Im kind of stuck in the same place

Comment: Add - `import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';` to app.module and import.

Answer (score 26):

A clarification of what @rmalviya suggested, I assume you are currently on Ionic version 3.x.x, for this version you have two ways of importing a native plugin and adding the respective providers for the plugin.

1) You could add the provider in your current page typescript file. like so:

```
  import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

  ...

  @Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [AngularFireAuth]
  })
```

2) Second method you could import it in your app.modules.ts and add the plugin into the providers

```
 import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

 ...

 providers: [
   StatusBar,
   SplashScreen,
   {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
   AngularFireAuth
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

[resolve here https://github.com/iglewski/Annotator/issues/3](https://github.com/iglewski/Annotator/issues/3)

app.component.spec.ts :

```
import { FirebaseApp, FirebaseAppConfig, AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { firebaseConfig } from './app.module';
describe('AppComponent', () => { 
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), //ajout
        AngularFireAuthModule, //ajout
        AngularFireDatabaseModule //ajout
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [IonicPageModule](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicPageModule/) system, then you'll need to import `AngularFireAuth` in your `app.module.ts` AND in your `page.module.ts` in the providers array.

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
... 
 providers: [AngularFireAuth]
...
```

page.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SignupPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SignupPage)
  ],
  exports: [
    SignupPage
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFireAuth
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but I managed to solved this by adding the following lines into my core modules.

CoreModule contains code that will be used to instantiate your app and load some core functionality.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* 3e. Import the angularfire2 thingy. */
**import {AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';**

import { AuthModule } from '../auth/auth.module';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    /* To allow the db to talk to the form. */
    **AuthModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,**
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```